# How to set a related object using HATEOAS?

Tags: rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I fail to consume a restful API with HATEOAS links generated from springboot repositories.

Consider the following model:

```
public class Order {
  private UUID id;
  private String orderNumber;
  private Location location;
}

public class Location {
  private String street;
  private String town;
}
```

Just for the sake of readability I left out any boilerplate code such as getters, setters and constructors.

After starting the service, I created an empty `Order`, that I can query like:

```
>curl http://localhost:8080/orders/1
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "orderNumber": "ON 0815", 
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1"
    },
    "location": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location"
    }
  }
}
```

Now if i call `curl http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location`, it returns `HTTP 404 - Not found`, which is reasonable, because I didn't set that yet.

Next I create the `Location` to set via `HTTP POST`:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost/8080/locations \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"street": "Bakerstreet 221B", "town": "London"}'
```

The service answers with:

```
{
  "street": "Bakerstreet 221B", 
  "town": "London",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/locations/1"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Now we get to the point, I am stuck at. **How do I link the `Location` to the `Order`?** None of my attempts worked out. I'd be grateful for any advice.

So far I tried:

**1. PUT the object**

```
>curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/orders/1 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"orderNumber": "ON 0815", "_links": {"self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1"}, "location": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location"}}}'
```

**2. PATCH the object**

```
>curl -XPATCH http://localhost:8080/orders/1 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"_links": {"self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1"}, "location": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location"}}}'
```

**3. POST to the link**

```
>curl -XPOST http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"street": "Bakerstreet 221B", "town": "London"}'
```

Comment: The new order endpoint returns the order number. Can't the new location endpoint return the 'location id' and then POST that to the order location endpoint you got from the new order? http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location/locationId

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. The API responds with an `HTTP 404 - Not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Management Summary**

```
>curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location \
  -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" \
  -d "http://localhost:8080/location/1"
```

---

**Detailed Description**

If I call the nested location uri with a `-I` flag and a forbidden method, the allowed methods are listed.

```
>curl -I -XPOST http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

HTTP/1.1 405 
Allow: GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 08:59:19 GMT
```

This means a `PUT` on this url must be valid. Putting on this url with an empty body yields:

```
>curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{}'

{"cause":null,"message":"Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map."}
```

After searching for this message, I found, that my `Content-Type` was wrong. I need to use `Content-Type: text/uri-list` and add the url of the location to set as body.

```
>curl -XPUT http://localhost:8080/orders/1/location \
  -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" \
  -d "http://localhost:8080/location/1"
```